# Html and Css border-bottom with 2 lines instead 1

Tags: html, css

I'm very begginer in HTML/CSS and I'm trying to set one line under my text, I used `border-bottom` in my CSS file, and it shows 2 lines under my text. I'm sure that I missed something but I just don't know what. I don't want to use `text-decoration:underline` because I need space between my text and my line. My problem is with the `<h3></h3>`

Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

### CSS / HTML

```css
body {
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Taviraj", serif;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #404040;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Taviraj", serif;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;
}

p {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-family: "Taviraj", serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin: 0px;
}

span {
  color: #ffff1a;
}

span:hover {
  color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<!--http://jonchretien.com/ -->
<head>
  <title>Jon Chretien | Front End Enginner</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jonchretiencom_style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Taviraj" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>My name is Jon Chretien. I'm a <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City" style="text-decoration:none"><span>NYC</span></a> based front end<br>
       engineer currently working on web apps for artists at<br>
        <a href="https://www.spotify.com/" style="text-decoration:none"><span>Spotify</span></a>. Previously at <a href="https://www.nytimes.com/" style="text-decoration:none"><span>The New York Times</span></a>.</p>
    <h3>Selected Works<h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `/` in  the closing `</h3>` tag, so the browser made two h3s out of it, creating two lines. Just inserting that slash into `</h3>` fixes it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Taviraj", serif;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #404040;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Taviraj", serif;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;
}

p {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-family: "Taviraj", serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin: 0px;
}

span {
  color: #ffff1a;
}

span:hover {
  color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<!--http://jonchretien.com/ -->
<head>
  <title>Jon Chretien | Front End Enginner</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jonchretiencom_style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Taviraj" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>My name is Jon Chretien. I'm a <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City" style="text-decoration:none"><span>NYC</span></a> based front end<br>
       engineer currently working on web apps for artists at<br>
        <a href="https://www.spotify.com/" style="text-decoration:none"><span>Spotify</span></a>. Previously at <a href="https://www.nytimes.com/" style="text-decoration:none"><span>The New York Times</span></a>.</p>
    <h3>Selected Works</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your code you need to close the `<h3></h3>` observe the **h3** is not close in your code